# google functions crash for execute error 500

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to Google Functions. This code is running in EC2 server but I want some schedule to execute. I want to execute this function everyday rather than write in Firebase, but I can't see a result after the test and it gives 500 error and crashes.

I have a requirements txt file:

```
python-binance==1.0.16
```

```
from binance.client import Client
import key

def hello_world(request):
       client = Client(api_key=key.Pkey, api_secret=key.Skey)

       acc_balance = float(client.futures_account()['totalMarginBalance'])

       return(acc_balance)
```

Comment: You can go to the logs and see what happens

Comment: it is just writen crash and 500 error written in logs